# Html button onclick event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want html button "News"to show my div "New" which is hidden here's my code( it's not working right now):

```
<div id = "Buttons">
    <button id="News">News</button><br>
    <button id="Marks">Marks</button><br>
    <button id="Averages">Averages</button><br>
    <button id="Forum">Forum</button><br>
</div>  
<div id="New">
    <p id="Newer">Text</p>
</div>

#New{
        display: none;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: grey;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#News").click(function() {
        $("#New").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: why don't you have <style> and <script> tags?

Comment: That code is working fine...You must have something else that you haven't showed in the example.

**JSBIN DEMO: http://jsbin.com/lovategiva/edit?html,js,output**

Comment: you write javascript in css styling scope

Comment: You need to make sure that you're loading JQuery first.

Comment: Try once with `<button  type="button" ...` note default behaviour of button is submit

Comment: Its work, check this https://jsfiddle.net/5fxyjxcr/

Comment: I believe button on its own tries to do a submission, so it won't work as intended as is. As Satpal said, make sure the type is set to `button`.

Comment: I have style and script tags in original code tried type="button" it didn't work

Comment: What a silly mistake my script tag was before jquery. Thank you guys for trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just put styles and scripts as text into your HTML page. You have have to tell the browser what it should do with the code.

First, you need to wrap your code in the appropriate tags:

```
<style>
#New{
    display: none;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: grey;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#News").click(function() {
        $("#New").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Second, you need to make sure JQuery is included before your script tag:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id = "Buttons">
    <button id="News">News</button><br>
    <button id="Marks">Marks</button><br>
    <button id="Averages">Averages</button><br>
   <button id="Forum">Forum</button><br>
</div>  
<div id="New">
    <p id="Newer">Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. please consider accepting the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id = "Buttons">
    <button id="News">News</button><br>
    <button id="Marks">Marks</button><br>
    <button id="Averages">Averages</button><br>
    <button id="Forum">Forum</button><br>
</div>  
<div id="New">
    <p id="Newer">Text</p>
</div>

<style>          <---------------this
#New{
        display: none;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: grey;
}
</style>          <---------------this

<script>          <---------------this
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#News").click(function() {
        $("#New").show();
    });
});
</script>         <---------------this
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're example is shortened up. Meaning, I'm assuming you have a `<script>` along with a `<style>`. If not, those are necessary. Also, I would seriously think about re-naming some of your stuff. For example, anytime you have a wrapper that represents a series of similar elements, use a class name instead of `id`. For example, I'd replace your `div` with a class instead of id like so:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button id="news">News</button><br>
    <button id="marks">Marks</button><br>
    <button id="averages">Averages</button><br>
    <button id="forum">Forum</button><br>
</div>  

<div id="New">
    <p id="Newer">Text</p>
</div>
```

That being said, your code works as is if you add the appropriate tags like so:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button id="news">News</button><br>
    <button id="marks">Marks</button><br>
    <button id="averages">Averages</button><br>
    <button id="forum">Forum</button><br>
</div>  

<style>
    #New{
        display: none;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: grey;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#News").click(function() {
            $("#New").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```